# My code not working properly for pagination in PHP, any suggestion?

Tags: paging

I am beginner in PHP . 
I want to display my mysql database contents from table to main front page display as paging (with limit) of number of items from table of database. My code display a format with exact paging and it plot items in first page (as: http://www.swaminarayantravel.com/category.php?sc=Trekking), But the problem is , when I try to go to page 2 from paging below, it take to the false page.
My code is:

```
<?php

//get the function
include_once ('function.php');
include_once ('includes/connect.php');

    $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 4;
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

    //to make pagination
  $sql = "category where category.category='$selcat'";
  ?>
<div class="records round">


  <ul class="homelist">
<?php

        //show records
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$sql} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
echo "<table>
<tr></tr>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {   ?>
<?php echo' <li > <img src="images/subcat/'.$row['file'] .'" height="100" width="100" alt="'.$row['subcategory'] .'"/> 
 <a class="title">'; 
$subcategory= $row["subcategory"];
                        echo "$subcategory"; 
echo'</a>
      <p align="justify">'; 
$detail= $row["subcat_detail"];
                        echo "$detail"; 
                        echo ' </p> '; ?> 
 <?php   }   ?> 
</table></div>
<?php   echo pagination($sql,$limit,$page);  ?>
```

and function.php page contains following codes:

```
<?php
```

function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url ='?'){
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2";

```
    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

    $prev = $page - 1;                          
    $next = $page + 1;
    $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
            }
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
            }
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
        }else{
            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
    }


    return $pagination;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, but you forget to add "sc=Trekking" to the request URL.
So, in your code, "$selcat" may become empty, and sql query return nothing.

Please try this:
http://www.swaminarayantravel.com/category.php?sc=Trekking&page=2

Maybe you should modify the "pagination" function.

Your site is wonderful.
I remember my travel in Nepal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, which URL I need to change? 
My function.php have code like this: 
 function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url ='?'){        
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
     $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
     $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 
$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
     $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;        
  
     $prev = $page - 1;       
     $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
     $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
     $pagination = "";
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I change my advice. 
You shuold not modify the "pagination" itself. 
You had better modify the caller side of the function.
For example,
(before)
<?php   echo pagination($sql,$limit,$page);  ?>
(after)
<?php   echo pagination($sql,$limit,$page, "?sc=Trekking&");  ?>

Comment: hitokun_s! Thank you so much for your continue support to me. As you have gave me suggestion it works perfect. But,I have to get Category dynamically, is there any other way that I can call category dynamically,it should be work for all category not only for Trekking. In the way you advice me, that works only for the Trekking category. But, for other category, it remain same. I just want to ask you for: 
Trekking is the row name 'category' from table category.In this 'category' i have many category , like Expedition, Rafting, Jungle Safari and so on. I need to pagination for all dynamically.

Comment: That's right.
if you want to set category flexibly,
you shuold set the variable "$selcat" ahead,
and call "pagination" like this:
pagination($sql,$limit,$page, "?sc=".$selcat."&");

Comment: and please add this code at the head of your code.
$selcat = $_GET["sc"];

Comment: Thank you so much, Hitokun_s, 
You are genius. 
The code you gave me work well. 
Now you also can see this working properly. 

Thank you so much. 

Also, in future, I would like to personally invite you to visit NEPAL.

Comment: Thank you!! In the future, I will visit my friend in Tulsipur, Napal.At that time, I will visit you too!